# why is this php variable undefined

Tags: php, mysqli, scope

Can anyone tell me why this does not work.

```
class class1 {

    private $database;

    function class1()  
    {  

        $database = $this->connect();


    } 

    private function connect(){

        $database = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","","db");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        return $database;

    }

    private function usedb(){
        $query = "some sql";
        mysqli_query($database,$query);
    }

}
```

I hope this simple example can portray my problem clearly enough. Anyway, when I run something like this I get an error displayed telling me that there has been a reference to an undefined variable "database" in the "usedb()" function. As if the variable has gone out of scope... Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Because the variable _has_ gone out of scope. `$database` is a local variable in your function; you should be using `$this->database` to access the class's property.

Comment: @andrewsi is right : in PHP, you *need* to use the `this` keyword to access class members, unlike, say, Java or C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because in `class1()` you declare another local variable `$database` through:

```
    $database = $this->connect();
```

To set and access the `$database` property of the class you should use:

```
    $this->database = $this->connect();
```

Same goes for the `usedb()` function:

```
private function usedb(){
    $query = "some sql";
    mysqli_query($this->database,$query);
}
```

So your final code should look like this:

```
class class1 {

     private $database;

     function class1()  
     {  
         $this->database = $this->connect();
     } 

     private function connect()
     {
         $database = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","","db");

         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
         {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
         }
         return $database;
     }

     private function usedb()
     {
         $query = "some sql";
         mysqli_query($this->database,$query);
     }
}
```

**NOTE:**

The same applies for the `$database` variable in `connect()` function. Although with an identical name, it has nothing to do with the outside `$database` variable, since that should be access using `$this->database` (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$database = $this->connect();
```

to

```
$this->database = $this->connect();
```

and all `$database` variable change to `$this->database` for `set`